# How to use QR decomposition of Extreme optimization

Tags: f#, f#-3.0

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7e952c45-2494-4650-aa61-89d5ea21f1f3/how-to-use-qr-decomposition-of-extreme-optimization

How to use QR decomposition of Extreme optimization

No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

```
let TwelvePalace : float[,] = Array2D.zeroCreate 4 3

TwelvePalace.[0,0] <- 1.0;
TwelvePalace.[0,1] <- 2.0;
TwelvePalace.[0,2] <- 3.0;

TwelvePalace.[1,0] <- 4.0;
TwelvePalace.[1,1] <- 5.0;
TwelvePalace.[1,2] <- 6.0;

TwelvePalace.[2,0] <- 7.0;
TwelvePalace.[2,1] <- 8.0;
TwelvePalace.[2,2] <- 9.0;

TwelvePalace.[3,0] <- 10.0;
TwelvePalace.[3,1] <- 11.0;
TwelvePalace.[3,2] <- 12.0;

let mutable iii = DenseMatrix.Create(TwelvePalace)
let QRProvider : QRDecomposition = iii.GetQRDecomposition()

let Q : DenseMatrix = QRProvider.OrthogonalFactor.ToDenseMatrix() // error here
let R : DenseMatrix = QRProvider.UpperTriangularFactor.ToDenseMatrix()
```

Comment: I did have a look at the screenshot (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/310857) and it looks like you have some mismatch between different versions/platforms of some of the libraries you're using. Does the toolbar say you are building "Windows Phone 7" application? Do you know if Extreme Optimization is supported on WP7? Are you referencing the right versions of the `dll`s? (it might be using some odd version of Silverlight that does not have all that Extreme Optimization needs to work...)

Comment: You will get better answers if you condense some of your information from the linked thread to your question here.  For example, you are missing at which point the error occurs, how you are compiling etc.

Comment: just building for console, add error here at Q, i have to check whether i am using correct dll at home tonight